# Jmeter 3.2 not counting all attributes

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have a 10MB page that we have to download in json format it has various headings with data under 2000 headings to be exact.

When I select a the page to be under 1996 headings in the request I retrive the exact count as soon as I select 2000 as the limit for the page it still will only retrive or count 1996 headings.

I know the script is working as it works with lower page sizes, Firefox and curl return the correct page of 2000.

Is there a limit on the size of Jmeter pages that needs changing?

Comment: Yes I do but the issue is on the first iteration and I have increased its size and even disabled it, still no luck

Comment: Found the problem in the end. when I was dumping the output to a log file to view what was coming down and the log file was limiting to about 10MB. That was corrected by setting document.max_size=0 but the file size did not increase beyond 10MB as there was a limit on the http download size defined in httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request. Setting this to a larger size downloaded all the data, created a large output file and also passed the validation :-)

Comment: you can add your own (well written) answer or delete the question if it's not relevant anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3), as per the [changelog](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html):

> JMeter will not truncate anymore by default responses exceeding 10 MB. If you want to enable this truncation, see property **httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request**

If you are not in position to perform the upgrade - add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=0
```

and after JMeter restart you should be able to see/process the full response